# Problemas con enrutamiento en CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Estoy intentando ejecutar un código en CodeIgniter en mi ordenador bajo Kubuntu. Para acceder a la home (http://localhost) no hay  problema ninguno. Pero al intentar acceder a otra URL (http://localhost/cliente) aparece el mensaje

> "The requested URL /cliente was not found on this server.".

Mi .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

El archivo  routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['cliente'] = 'clientes';
$route['produto'] = 'produtos';
```

Tengo los archivos Clientes.php y Produtos.php en la carpeta application/controllers.

En el archivo config.php: `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Lo que mas me extraña es que para acceder a la home no hay ningún problema. Solo da el error cuando intento cualquier otra URL tipo http://localhost/cliente.

El controlador:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Clientes extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ci_sga_model');
        $this->load->library(array('session','email'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('clientes');
    }

}
```

Comment: Lo agregué al final de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En el `root` de tu proyecto debes añadir el siguiente `.htaccess`. Este archivo te permite controlar el ruteo de las urls en CodeIgniter sin el `index.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/fechas/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Después, vas a agregar otro `.htaccess` dentro de tu carpeta `application`

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

En tu archivo `routes.php` vas a configurar lo siguiente:

```
...
$route['Clientes'] = 'clientes';
```

Por favor nota que para algunos servidores le es sensible reconocer mayúsculas y minúsculas. El problema que estás teniendo es que no encuentra `clientes` porque tu servidor es sensible y lo correcto sería espeficiarle en el `routes.php` el `Clientes`
con la **C** mayúscula.

El controlador `Clientes.php` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Clientes extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ci_sga_model');
        $this->load->library(array('session','email'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('clientes');
    }
}
```

Si hasta este punto nada funciona, trata de agregar un `Helper` para que pueda ayudarte en el tema de las urls. Puedes encontrar más información acerca de ellos en este [enlace](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#loading-this-helper).

`$this->load->helper('url_helper');`

> El código se agrega dentro del constructor del controlador `Clientes.php`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiar la linea en .htaccess

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Por

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cliente/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

O bien alternativamente puedes escribir

```
    RewriteBase /cliente/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

La razón por la que falla es que cuando el mod_rewrite reescribe la url no incluye la carpeta en la que se encuentra el proyecto. Eso puedes agregarlo agregándola explícitamente en la regla.

Comment: ¿por qué? debes explicar todo ese código

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que el mod_rewrite en Apache no estaba activado. La solución está en este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029066/route-not-work-in-codeigniter-for-others-routes-than-home
Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: si vas a usar la respuesta de otro usuario de SO en inglés, es tu deber traducir la respuesta y dejar el link como crédito al autor original; de otro modo al solo poner el enlace tu respuesta se toma de baja calidad

Comment: Si tan solo hubieras leído mi respuesta, hubieras tenido una solución 9 horas antes de esta auto respuesta.